# I broke the visual studio code coverage window. How do I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I somehow managed to detach the grid from the code coverage report window. It is now sitting in the top left of my screen, and resizes when I resize the code coverage window.

It also doesn't render any results, so I can't even use it where it is.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on:

- How to resolve this?
- How to prevent this from happening again?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You can always right click on the Windows taskbar and use Cascade Windows or Windows stacked...etc

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't help as it is a WPF child window that is rendered incorrectly, not the main window that is affected by the Cascade Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else coming here, this is apparently a known bug in VS when restoring the Code Coverage window as part of a layout.

[Microsoft Bug Report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/625438/white-box-shows-after-windows-update.html)